# View is not in the Window hierarchy using Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue, transition

I've already searched **stackOverFlow** for solutions and found a bunch of threads but none of them helped in my case.

From a plain **Sprite Kit** template:

I managed to create a table with prototype cells in the storyboard and populated them with a plist. Good so far!
I also managed to show the `UITableViewController` from my `SKScene` with the following code:

```
UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
[vc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToTable" sender:nil];
```

I can go back to my `SKScene` with a segue from a Navigation Bar Back Button.

BUT when I try to show the `UITableViewController` again I get the following error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <TableViewController: 0x135d78580> on <ViewController: 0x135e0c2e0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

What can I do to segue between my `SpriteKit` **scene** and the `UITableViewController`?

EDIT:
I'm using NSNotificationCenter now.
Simply add a notification in my main ViewController which calls

```
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the method on `viewDidLoad:` method? Somethimes calling a modal view controller within `viewDidLoad:` gives this kind of problem.

You can solve this problem calling it from the `viewDidAppear:` method.

Comment: I'm calling the **performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToTable"** from a custom method in my SKSzene. The transition back to the scene is a modalSegue added by drag&drop.
I am presenting the SKSzene from ViewWillLayoutSubViews.

Comment: I think it's the same issue than viewDidLoad. Your initial view may not yet loaded